# Operator '==' can not be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'Task<int>'

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-core-3.1

In ASP.NET Core 3.1, I am trying to make my methods asynchronous.

Here is my code:

```
public async Task<int> GetMaxNews()
{
    return await _context.PNewses.MaxAsync(s => s.Id);
}
```

and I use this method in this code snippet:

```
public async Task<List<PNews>> LastNews()
{
    return await _context.PNewses.Where(s => s.Id == GetMaxNews()).ToList();
}
```

I get this error:

> Operator '==' can not be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'Task'

Can anybody help me? What is the problem?

Comment: This doesn't really make much sense, you are essentially trying to return a list of results with a Max Id. Ids are usually identity columns clustered and unique. In most cases there would only be one. In which cases you would just `OrderByDescending` then `FirstOrDefault`. if for some weird reason you actually needed this, it migth be better to do 2 round trips, get the max then `where` by that max

Comment: As the error suggegst: `GetMaxNews()` is returning a `Task<int>` which you will have to  `await` somehow to get the resulting `int` of it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo can't call other function in EF, at first get the result of the 'GetMaxNews' then use it. like below sample code:

```
public async Task<int> GetMaxNews()
{
    return await _context.PNewses.MaxAsync(s => s.Id);
}


public async Task<List<PNews>> LastNews()
{
    int ResultOfGetMaxNews = await GetMaxNews();
    return await _context.PNewses.Where(s => s.Id == ResultOfGetMaxNews ).ToListAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `GetMaxNews()` it returns a `Task<Int>`. When you await the task, you get back an int. Want something that looks like...

```
... Where(s => s.Id == await GetMaxNews()) ...
```

Comment: public async Task<List<PNews>> LastNews()
        {
            return await _context.PNewses.Where( s => s.Id == await GetMaxNews()).ToList();
        }